# Append new values to the similar keys python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, tree

I have a tree and i'm traversing the tree using map methods(i.e nodes with similar keys must come together) assuming root node is marked 0,left of the root is -1,right of the root is +1. Traverse the complete tree and assign the HD(horizontal distance from root) of each node as the key of the node and the data of the node as a value. Now i want to append all the values with similar keys at one place in dictionary like **{0: ['10','13'], 1: ['12'], -2: ['12'], -1: ['11']}** for the below created tree.

**Code**

```
class node:
    dict1={}
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

    def check_if_exists(self,hd,root):
      if not self.dict1:
          self.dict1[hd] = [root.data]
      else:
            if hd in self.dict1.keys():  ###Checking if key already exists for some node
                self.dict1[hd].append(root.data)
            else:
                self.dict1[hd] = [root.data]

    def vertical_order_tree(self,root,hd):
        if root:
                self.check_if_exists(hd,root)
                self.vertical_order_tree(root.left,hd-1)
                self.vertical_order_tree(root.right,hd+1)


root=node("10")
root.left=node("11")
root.left.left=node("12")
root.right=node("12")
#root.right.left=node("13")
root.vertical_order_tree(root,0)
print(root.dict1)
```

**Output:**

```
self.dict1[hd].append(root.data)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Appending the similar values is causing the issue. Anyone can catch the bug here. i'm not good at handling dictionaries.

Comment: The error indicates that `self.dict1[hd]` is a string, while you think that it is a list. You cannot append to a string.

Comment: yes i know that but where and what to change is the problem for me. So a correct code can help me here

Comment: Replace the `self.dict1[hd] = root.data` in `if not self.dict1:`, with `self.dict1[hd] = [root.data]`. You mistakenly inserted a string in your dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: {0: ['13'], 1: ['12'], -2: ['12'], -1: ['11']}   After being replaced @VasilisG.  10 got overwritten with 13

Comment: Another change that I forgot to mention is: Erase the `for k,v in self.dict1.items():
            if k==hd:` and simply put `if hd in self.dict1.keys():`.See the edit in your question.

Comment: That actually worked. but how does it make a difference with the for and if statement i was using @VasilisG.

Comment: The difference is that you cannot modify a list while you 're iterating over it. With the suggested solution, no modification is taking place during iteration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159918/discussion-between-codaholic-and-vasilis-g).

Answer (score 1):

The error `says self.dict[hd]` is a string. Try using `self.dict[hd]+=root.data` instead of `self.dict[hd].append(root.data)`. Of course only if `root.data` is another string.

If you want the value of that key to be a list then I'd suggest first making an empty list at that key and then appending